# bash alias for "cd directory; ls"

Tags: bash, alias

How do I create BASH alias for:

I type in `cdd directory` and what that does is `cd directory` and then `ls`?

Comment: A note (though others have mentioned) aliases can not have arguments. You need a function.

Comment: Why don't you use `ls directory` instead?

Answer (score 8):

It'd be easier to make a function:

```
cdd () 
{
    cd $1
    ls
}
```

Of course, you can name the function whatever you like. Put it in your .bashrc or .profile or whatever it is on your system.

Comment: does that automatically mkae cdls an alias?

Comment: @funk-shun it makes `cdd` a function, which in practice acts almost exactly like an alias would. Functions are more powerful and take arguments, though.

Comment: so i take it $2 refers to the second argument in a command call? `-r` in the case of `ls -C -r`?

Comment: @funk-shun yes.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a function that you'll put in your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`, or whatever):

```
cdd(){
  to=$1
  cd ${to}
  ls
}
```

Once you put this in your appropriate file, you can use `cdd <directory>` just like an alias.

Comment: This will break on directories with spaces in them

Answer (score 2):

Just like the other function examples, but this one will work with directories with spaces, without needing to escape the spaces.

```
cdd() {
    cd "$*"
    ls
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alias dirXandLs='cd directory; ls'
```

I bet you really want to make directory be an argument, i.e. $1. can't do that with aliases.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1708802&p=10569668#post10569668) is your answer. you can add this function to your .bashrc file:

```
function cd(){ builtin cd "$*" && ls }
```